# Hibernate storing empty string creates white space in DB.

Tags: java, hibernate, sybase

i am using sybase db and hibernate as ORM tool,
I am dealing with Person object, which contains name as String variable,
i have used varchar datatype in db side
when i create object of Person as

```
Person p=new Person();
p.setName(null);    
session.saveOrUpdate(p);
```

this works fine

but when i put empty string in name it creates white space in db.

```
Person p=new Person();
p.setName("");
session.saveOrUpdate(p);
```

why this is happening ?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Do you mean that when you read the Person object back, the name is set to " " (0x20) instead of "" (empty string)?

Comment: What is the result of if(new String("") == null){System.out.println("\"\" is equal to null")}else{System.out.println("\"\" is not equal to null")} ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its the database padding that adds the white space and nothing to do with hibernate.

Refering to

[Manual link](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebook...190;pt=16190#X),

"Adaptive Server truncates entries to the specified column length without warning or error, unless you set string_rtruncation on. See the set command in the Reference Manual for more information. The empty string, ""or '', is stored as a single space rather than as NULL. Thus, "abc" + "" + "def" is equivalent to "abc def", not to "abcdef"."

Two things you could do:

- have your application explicitly insert NULL (which is kind of what
  it should do since the empty string is not equivalent to NULL)
- put an insert/update trigger on that table (or tables) which
  intercepts the empty string and converts it to NULL

Answer (score 1):

Empty is a string value and hibernate think like it is a string with a value empty So it will create it. You can check "".equals(..) that means java treats "" as a value.